# Java mail - Couldn't connect to host

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email Java application, following guide on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm

When I try to run it, copypasted first code from link above, I get an error that it could not connect to host, which is a localhost. Here is a result when I ping localhost:

```
Pinging Home-PC [::1] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
Reply from ::1: time<1ms
```

Since I am greatly inexperienced in communications, I do not know what went wrong, and yet again, I need help. So, is the issue in my localhost not being properly configured, or is something wrong with my code? What could I do?

I am using Tomcat v8.0 server.

I am also adding console output:

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
nested exception is:
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2054)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at test.Test.main(Test.java:51)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:329)
at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:236)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2020)
... 7 more
```

Comment: Answering pings doesn't mean the SMTP port is open... Did you check if the port is open?

Comment: You must change properties with your own properties.It will be better if you post your code and we can see what is problem.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, that you do not have an `SMTP`-Server installed on your local machine. For testing purposes, start an instace of [FakeSMTP](https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/). If it is up and running, programs are able to connect and to drop their mail.

If you want to experiment a little (assuming you have a Windows box), there is [Hamstermail](http://hamster.volker-gringmuth.de/) (Site is in german - be warned *;-)*)

> Here is a result when I ping localhost

That only shows that a server responds to an `Echo Request`. This does neither mean, that the server has a SMTP-service running, nor does it mean, if the server does not answer, that the server is down - sometimes, admins block `ICMP-Echo-Requests`.

Sometimes a `telnet $server 25` allows connecting to the mail-server.

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

This shows, that the Service is not active aka *the port is closed*.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much, I am making progress now! When I start instance of FakeSMTP, it is recieving mails. So,does this mean I must somehow configure my Tomcat server, if I want to send actual mails?

Comment: You need an SMTP-server to actually send mail. Beware of sending mail from your localhost - most of the time these are marked as Spam. It would be better to choose a known mail provider.